# What would attract an Enderman into a pit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm working on an Enderman farm that really hasn't been done before and I'm fairly excited about it, but I've run into a hitch. I've experimented around until I found a way to get Endermen to reliably teleport to a floating pad, which can be seen here:

[image]

I'm now wanting these guys to go down into the hole you can see in the middle of the pad. Unfortunately they seem to be avoiding it as much as possible. What would be a good way to trick them into thinking the hole is a solid block so that they might be tempted to walk into it? I thought that perhaps trap doors or ladders could be used to some extend due to their hitboxes being unique, but I'm not entirely sure. Any ideas on this?

*Edit*: After experimenting with torches a bit, it seems like they slowly edge away from light sources, meaning if I place light around key areas on the edge they should be driven straight to the center. It seems to be helping so far, at least in some limited testing.

*Edit 2:* I have been looking at the decompiled version of the game code and I haven't found a great deal. From a quick glance it seems that Endermen simply behave as any other mob when they are not in the random teleportation state. And that means they should have a random path applied at random times, which means the light levels shouldn't matter. This doesn't match up with what I've observed though, so maybe I missed something in my quick pass thorough the code.

Comment: Stand in the pit yourself and look at one. It should not take too long for him to get near. Or hit it first and then walk in the pit yourself. Did you try a trapdoor with a switch or timer already?

Comment: I don't know if this has been fixed, but putting signs around the edge of the hole used to work.

Comment: @MennoGouw: The point isn't to look at each guy to make him come in the hole, as this was meant to be an XP farm which operates quite quickly. I'm sure that would work but it's not ideal.

Comment: @fredley: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work, looks like they're still avoiding entering it as much as possible.

Comment: Is making the platform a bit smaller and pushing them into the pit with pistons an option? I didn't test this, just a wild guess.

Comment: @Arperum: Yes that is an option. I was wanting to avoid having to use piston pushers in this setup but if nothing else seems to be reliable that might be my only alternative.

Comment: How about dispensers with arrows? I think those should knock them back a bit. The hole would probably need to be next to a wall/fence, though, so they don't fly over... And it also might be a bit arrow expensive.

Comment: @Humungus: That would be interesting, but I'd rather avoid adding something non-sustainable to this since that goes against the spirit of a farm.

Comment: @sudorm-rf Have you tried putting the farm extremely high up (such that there is no visible land for the mobs to spawn on), using endstone and standing about 20 blocks away? That way instead of trying get them into the hole they spawn there, could then use pistons to push them into a more confined space

Comment: @AbstractChaos: This farm is built quite a ways from the island, and I'm using a shifting floor to conglomerate them on a much larger pad, and I'm forcing them to teleport to this smaller pad by using some unique mechanics. :) Piston pushers are of course an option, but I was trying to avoid that since I wanted this farm to be unique in all respects.

Comment: would carpet work? I haven't played in a while and don't know if carpet can be suspended in mid air.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual way to do this (for any mob) is put open trap doors in the pit. Mobs avoid falls now, but will treat trap doors as walkable blocks regardless of whether they're open or closed, wander over them, and fall.

Comment: I believe signs also work, and would be slightly more efficient. However, the mob AI may have been changed to recognize signs as non-solid. Usually I would suggest water to push them in, but of course endermen would reject that.

Comment: @TheUgly I'm not sure, but I suspect the AI has been changed. Most new fall designs use open trap doors now, and though I haven't done any sciencing on it, it *seems* like using trap doors has been working better than signs in my own machines.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the trap doors help them once they're walking toward the pit, but it seems like they're still avoiding the pit itself and clustering toward the edges. Maybe I could just be smart and put the pit in a circle around the edges, since that seems like where they're wanting to go. I'll give it a bit more time to see if I get any other answers, otherwise I'll accept your answer in a bit.

Comment: @sudorm-rf The more edges that are available for falling, the more their random walking will make them fall. Definitely take advantage of every edge!

Answer (score 2):

Endermen now attack Endermites, so if you put an Endermite in a Minecart the Enderman will attack it.

Make sure it is spawned in survival though.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's the case. In fact, that's how I have my current farm set up. I use a named Endermite that I keep in a minecart in the middle of a large circular pad. However, what I was working on before involved the AI of Snow Golems to force the Endermen to teleport onto a separate pad. I thought it was pretty cool, but it doesn't work as well as the Endermite behavior does.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sticky pistons rigged to pull the floor out from underneath the endermen. This can be done if you are tricky enough with redstone contraptions. If you don't know how to use redstone in this way there are plenty of youtube videos, and the minecraft wiki can fill you in on the basics of redstone.

Comment: I suppose that could work, and I've made several floor removers before, so that wouldn't be a problem. But I'd still like to take advantage of some mob behaviors here, as it seems like there should be a way to drive them where I want them to go instead of relying on their random behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you put pressure plates connected to pistons, when the enderman walk onto the pressure plates they will set off the piston's causing them to fall into the pit.